# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Navbar' in 'C:\Users\default\my-first-app\src'

Tags: css, reactjs, module, components

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./styles.css";
 import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
 import Main from "../components/Main";

export default function App() {
    return (
       <>
       <Navbar />
       <Main />
       </>
)
}





import  ReactDOM  from "react-dom";
import App from "./App.js"
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")) 




import React from "react"
import "./styles.css"
export default function Navbar(){
    return (
      <>
      <header>
        <nav className = "nav">
            <img src="./.png" />
            <ul>
                <li>React Facts</li>
                <li>React Course - Project 1 </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    </>
)
}
```

Thats App.js, Index.js, Navbar.js. Everytime I run I get the same error I've tried changing file paths with ./ and without same error. It switches every time between these three. Folder structure. I installed style loader as well.

```
Src
 components
   Navbar
   Main
App
Index
css
```

Error messages:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.styles.css' in 'C:\Users\default\my-first-app\src'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Main' in 'C:\Users\default\my-first-app\src'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Navbar' in 'C:\Users\default\my-first-app\src'
```

Folder structure

```
src
  components
    Navbar
    Main
App
index
styles
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your folder structure, your App is a sibling of your "styles.css" and "Src" folders.

To import Navbar and Main from App, the statements should be:

```
import Navbar from "./src/components/Navbar"
import Main from "./src/components/Main"
```

To get styles.css from Navbar:

```
import "../styles.css"
```